# RegExp regular expression find & replace whole words only

Tags: regex

I should preface this by stating that I'm working with VB6 & RegExp

I'm attempting to find and substitute whole words, by "whole words" I mean a valid match is not a substring of another word, although some special characters will be ok. I'm a novice at regular expressions. This is what I was trying:

```
([^a-z]+)(Foo)([^a-z]+)
```

It seems close but I'm having some trouble in certain situations.

For example, if I find the string

```
Foo Foo
```

or

```
Foo(Foo)
```

or anywhere a line ends with Foo and the following line begins with Foo

```
This is a line with Foo
Foo starts the next line
```

In any of these cases only the first Foo is matched.

Well, maybe it isn't a problem with the match but rather my replace method. I don't know exactly how I can verify that. I'm using groups to replace whatever bounding char is matched by the expression, like so:

```
regEX.Replace(source, "$1" & newstring & "$3")
```

So in summary I want to avoid matching:
FooBar
BarFoo

Any of the following would be valid matches:

Foo Foo
Foo Bar
Foo_bar
Foo.bar
Foo, bar
Foo(bar)
Foo(Foo)

If anyone can kindly show me the proper way to do this I would much appreciate it!

**edited**

Looks like I spoke a little too soon regarding the first solution below. After a little testing and some further reading, I see that underscore is a word char and thus the above pattern won't match it. I came up with this which does the trick, is there a better way?

```
(\b)(Foo)(\b|_)

regEX.Replace(source, "$1" & newstring & "$3")
```

It works, but seems a little sloppy.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the "word boundary" expression `\b`.

Perhaps something as simple as this will do:

```
(.*)\bFoo\b(.*)
```

FYI, the word boundary expression `\b` is a zero-width match *between* a word character `\w` and a non-word character `[^\w]` or visa versa, and consumes no input.

---

Underscore and digit characters are considered "word characters", so `Foo_Bar`, `Bar_Foo`, and `Foo123` wouldn't match. To rectify that, so that *any* non-letter is considered "end of word" (including start and end of input), use look arounds:

```
(?i)(.*(?<![^a-z]))Foo((?![^a-z]).*)
```

Comment: BIG thanks. I have so much to learn about regular expressions. I did have to make a small change, but it seems to have done the trick. Simply \bFoo\b

Comment: Well, it wasn't quite perfect. I amended my original post above. Comments are welcome.

Comment: underscore is considered a "Word character", so `\b` won't match between a letter and an underscore. There *is* a way to do it though. Let me know if you want me to show you

Comment: @F.Vosnim the pattern is fine and compiles for me. Regex101 uses a flag for ignore case rather than `(?i)`, and doesn’t seem to understand negative look behinds. Looks like a bug there to me. I have always disliked regex101; I find it non intuitive (and also it doesn’t work on mobile devices, which is where I do much of my posting).