# Search and Replace ENTIRE WORDS ONLY in VB

Tags: vb6

A word processor program features a search and replace function. However, partial words (character combinations found within words) are also replaced. To fix this, I plan to remove extra spaces and use the split function to change the string into an array of words by using " " as a delimiter.

However, once I search through the array, replace the appropriate words, and put the array back into a string separated by spaces, the original formatting of the user will be lost. For example, if the original string was **"This is a            sentence."** and the user wanted "a" to be replaced with "the", the output will be "This is the sentence.", with no additional spaces.

So, my question is whether there is any way to search and replace entire words only while still preserving the formatting (extra spaces) of the user in Visual Basic.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697483/regexp-regular-expression-find-replace-whole-words-only) seems to contain what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the **Split** function without removing your extra spaces first your array will have empty items in it so you would not lose the extra spaces and can reconstruct your document with the original formatting in tact.

Answer (score 4):

What about using a regex?

In a regex the code `\b` is a word boundary so for example the regex `\ba\b` will match *a* only when  *a* is a whole word.

So for example your code would be:

```
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\ba\b"
Dim regex As New RegExp

regex.Global = True
regex.Pattern = strPattern
result = regex.Replace("This is a sentence.", "the")
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is your formatting lost? If you split the text by space, just attach a space after each element when composing it back from an array. But you will also have to take into account words that end not with a space but punctuation.

in "This is a simple sentence, eh?", "eh" will be stored as "eh?" because u split by space. So you will have to program a complex punctuation-friendly formula or simply use regex. Be prepared - regex is... tricky.