# I want to replace a whole word in a paragraph in java, but it is also replacing characters that match. Don't know how to do it

Tags: java

E.g if the string i entered is

`"hello this is java"`

and I want to replace `is` with `at`, but output java shows is

`"hello that at java"`

code is

```
String a[]; 
String s1; 
s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the string"); 
a = s1.split("[\s\.]"); 
String s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace "); 
String s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace with"); 
String s; 
for(int i=0; i<=a.length; i++) { 
    s = a[i]; 
    if(s.equals(s2) == true) { 
       char[] string1 = s2.toCharArray(); 
       char[] string2 = s.toCharArray(); 
       if(Arrays.equals(string1, string2) == true) { 
           System.out.println("here i am"); 
           String q = s1.replace( s2, s3);  
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,q,"Array values",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); 
         break; 
       }
```

Comment: You probably want to use a regular expression to replace whole words. Once you have the appropriate regular expression you can use String.replaceAll. For the regex bit see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697483/regexp-regular-expression-find-replace-whole-words-only

Comment: That is because you are replacing every occurence of 'is' with 'at'. What you might to for this simple case is trying string splitting, modification and reconcatanation.

Comment: @Sıddık Açıl I tried splitting. but couldn't get your answer. Can you please explain it.

Comment: There is no code. Please paste the code into the question as text, with formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

A major problem in your code is using the counter of the loop up to the length of the array which will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the index of the array ranges from `0` to `the length of array - 1`.

**Do it as follows:**

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the string");
        String s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace ");
        String s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace with");

        String a[] = s1.split("\\s+");// Split the string on space(s)
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            //Replace the word in the array
            if (a[i].equals(s2)) {
                a[i] = s3;
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.join(" ", a));
    }
}
```

**Alternatively,** you can use regex, `"\\b" + s2 + "\\b"` where `\\b` pertains to word boundary.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the string");
        String s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace ");
        String s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace with");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s1.replaceAll("\\b" + s2 + "\\b", s3));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regular expressions](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) with the "word boundary" expression (\b) along with [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), like so:

```
String word = "is";
String replacement = "at";

String result = "is this? This is, an island".replaceAll("\\b" + word + "\\b", replacement);
// result: "at this? This at, an island"
```

In your case, you would want to replace this line:

```
String q = s1.replace(s2, s3);
```

with this line:

```
String q = s1.replaceAll("\\b" + s2 + "\\b", s3);
```

Here is the complete example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the string"); 
        String s2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace "); 
        String s3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the word to replace with"); 
        String q = s1.replaceAll( "\\b" + s2 + "\\b", s3);  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,q,"Array values",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE); 
    }
}
```

Comment: using expression was also not helpful.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I just tested this in jshell and it works as expected.

Comment: For example: "hello this is java".replaceAll("\\bis\\b", "at");

Comment: yes, I want to replace the word from paragraph which user enters. then it asks for the word which word I want to replace. Then it asks for the word replace with. lastly I displays the  new string. This is what I want....but it is not giving required output.

Comment: @Attia, see the latest edit to my answer, which should directly address how this fits into your code.

Comment: i tried this didnt solve the problem. e.g "It is an irrelevant thing. you have to be anticompetitive". when I enter this string and replace an with un, it shows "It is un irrelevant thing. you have to be unticompetitive".

Comment: thanks for editing. kindly try to solve this issue. need  urgently

Comment: I've added a complete example for you, which I tested with "It is an irrelevant thing. you have to be anticompetitive", "an" and "un" successfully.