# Replace word in a file

Tags: python, file

So I have to replace words in a given file. The problem is you may have this subtext in some other word which shouldn't be replaced, so `string.replace()` can't be used here. The word also may have symbols like `".,;:!?"`
For example in the given file there is `Bobtail has a tail.` and all words "tail" must be replaced with "head", so the answer in this situation shall be `Bobtail has a head.`

Comment: You can use regular expression : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11697492/2681662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a regular expression for such complicated string searches. In python, this can be done by importing the RE module. Then you can use the `search()` method to find any given regular expression in a string. The result is accessible through the `group()` method. Given that you know how to loop ove the contents of a file, you're solution looks like this:

```
import re

substring = some_file.txt
result =[]
for e in substring:
    regexp = re.search("(\s|\.|\,|\?|\!|\:|\;)tail(\s|\.|\,|\?|\!|\:|\;)",e,1)
    if regexp.group() is not None:
        result.push(e.replace(regexp.group(),"head"))
    else:
        result.push(e)
```

You can practice more with regular expressions here:
https://regexr.com/

For simplicity, I didn't include every special character. Note that you have to escape them with backslash character. Use `\s` for whitespaces.

Comment: The regex would probably look something like this: `[ .,:!;?]SUBSTRING[ .,:!;?]`. Note that you need to escape special symbols inside of `SUBSTRING` so they don't get interpreted by regex

Comment: I practiced a little and came to the regexp that is given in the code. \s can be used for whitespaces

Comment: I made the comment before it was added, and I'm not sure why you would have `(\.|\,|\:|...)` just to have `\s` there. If you really wanted an `\s` you would write `(\s|[..:;?!])...`

Comment: Also, you should replace only the middle group and not the whole thing.

Comment: You are right, you can do without the overly complicated parenthesis. I just made this one quickly in regexr.com, and checked if it selected the required parts. There is probably a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution which may be good enough for you, is by adding some spaces around the word you want to replace in the `.replace()` call.

Using your example:

```py
str = "Bobtail has a tail."
print(str.replace("tail", "nose")) # Bobnose has a nose.
print(str.replace(" tail", "nose")) # Bobtail has a nose.
```

The next step up is to use a regular expression to find the strings to replace. This is a bit more complex and case specific, so you may want to use something like [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to try and build one.

Comment: This will not work for words starting with tail.. i.e Bobtail and tailBob have a tail. This will give Bobtail and nosebob have a nose.

Comment: I assumed it may not work in all the OP's cases, so RegEx would be the next best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan P mentioned, what you are looking for is the python [re](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#module-re) module, particularly the [sub](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.sub) method.

Take this string for example:

```
s = "Bobtail has a !!tail.!! and the ..tail> is just a part of Bobtails' body"
```

Using the regex word boundry operator `\b`

```
resulting_string = re.sub('\\btail\\b','head', s)
"Bobtail has a !!head.!! and the ..head> is just a part of Bobtails' body"
```

To eliminate special characters you could go for something more complex in the regex pattern, like:

```
resulting_string = re.sub('\\W\\S?tail\\S*','head',s)
"Bobtail has a head and the head is just a part of Bobtails' body"
```